# How can identify which java/javascript file in the code generates the specific cookie?

Tags: javascript, java, cookies, browser

I have a project implemented by java,after running the code, I can see there are some encrypted cookies related to the login page, but I can not see any written code in that page. I was wondering, how can I find the block of codes which generate those cookie?

Comment: are you, by any chance, running the project through IntelliJ's IDEA? If so, bare in mind the projects run in a kind of wrapper made by the IDE - it does set a few cookies. If not, dare I ask if you simply tried searching for the string "cookie"?

Comment: I am using eclipse. and also searched all the cookies inside the project, but still can't find where those cookies come from

Comment: If you are running your project through some kind of a "start" button in your IDE, it most likely builds a wrapper around it and sets cookies to your browser. Try running the project outside the IDE.

Comment: I am running the project outside of eclipse